# FlowableOnBackpressureDrop ignores Subscription's request method

Tags: rx-java

I tried below

```
Flowable.interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

      private Subscription subscription;

      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        this.subscription.request(1L);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Long t) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(300L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(t);

        subscription.request(1L);
      }

      ...
    });
```

I expected that I might get something like 0, 3, 6...
However, I got 0, 1, 2, 3...
because Flowable got `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` at first.

I checked FlowableOnBackpressureDrop and I found

```
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        if (SubscriptionHelper.validate(this.s, s)) {
            this.s = s;
            actual.onSubscribe(this);
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
```

Since the value which I set on request method wasn't used,
I think that backpressure is not working.

Is this a bug or a right action?

I tried on RxJava 2.0.0-RC2 and RC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observeOn` requests and buffers 128 elements upfront so there is nothing to drop for some time at the beginning. If you leave it running 128 * 300ms it will start skipping values. You can set the prefetch amount with an overload to 1 and see values dropped fairly quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Now, I know that  the cause is `observeOn` and how to fix. I added 1 to observeOn's parameter and I got what I want. Although I don't feel comfortable about that the backpressure drop option buffers items because I have to care about not only request method but also observeOn method, RxJava 1.1 acts as same. So it is the way from the beginning. I wonder whether anyone has trouble about this.